# os remove any file but .py file from directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to find a way to write a script if `any` CSV file exists in a directory, remove it. How can I write this without specifying a specific file name?

Is it possible to write if any file exists but a `.py` file extension, remove it with `os`?

```
import os

if os.path.exists("AHU4_data_CSV.csv"):
  os.remove("AHU4_data_CSV.csv")

else:
  print("The file does not exist")
```

Comment: walk through every file and see if any `endswith('.csv')`

Comment: `.lower().endswith(".csv")` in case of .CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - just list all the files/folders in the directory, and if they don't end with .py, remove them.

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not filename.endswith('.py'):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            os.remove(filename)
        else:
            os.rmdir(filename)
```

Comment: Hello, could one ever incorporate an `or` statement to include .csv & .png files in addition to .py?  Something like: `if not filename.endswith('.py') or not filename.endswith('.csv') or not filename.endswith('.png'):`

Comment: `and` would work better than `or` there (`if not (any of these)` and `if not(this) and not(this) and not(this)` are logically equivalent. But yes, that would be straightforward to do.

Comment: Ah ok, so a `if not filename.endswith('.py','.csv','png'):` would also work? Thanks for your help

Comment: No, because the `endswith()` function doesn't work that way - but `if not (filename.endswith('.py') or filename.endswith('.csv') or filename.endswith('.png')):` should work

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this :

```
import os

root = "e:/"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            print("removed: " + os.path.join(root, file) )
            os.remove( os.path.join(root, file) )
```

It will remove your `E` directories all CSV files including subfolder's `CSV` files from E.

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this

```
import os
mydir='path/to/dir/with/files'

for file in os.listdir(mydir):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        os.remove(os.path.join(mydir,file))
```